# upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 via CD/USB image

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 14.04

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed and have 14.04 iso file. Is there any way to enable upgrading using this image file and not have to download lots of files?

It's because, the Internet is a bit of a problem where I live.

Comment: My question refers to the fact that upgrade from LTS to LTS is disabled and postponed to the release of 14.04.1. The addressed question does not deal with LTS-to-LTS issue.

Comment: @Mousa: The answer in that dupe link says that offline upgrade using the iso file is not supported. So, whatever version you are using (LTS/normal), the answer would be same -- "No, offline upgrade is not supported".